# mitmproxy installation by the python setuptools easy_install got error decoding "ascii" on windows 7

Tags: python, mitmproxy

When I try to **install mitmproxy** by the **easy_install** on **windows 7**, I got **error with ascii**.

Here is the console result from cmd.

> **C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install D:_python\mitmproxy-0.9.2**
>
> Processing mitmproxy-0.9.2
>
> Writing D:_python\mitmproxy-0.9.2\setup.cfg
>
> Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir D:_python\mitmproxy-0.9.2\egg-dist-tmp -qdtwhc
>
> zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
>
> libmproxy.utils: module references **file**
>
> libmproxy.contrib.pyparsing: module MAY be using inspect.stack
>
> libmproxy.contrib.jsbeautifier.unpackers.**init**: module references **path** mitmproxy 0.9.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
>
> Installing mitmdump script to C:\Python27\Scripts
>
> Installing mitmproxy script to C:\Python27\Scripts
>
> Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
>
> Processing dependencies for mitmproxy==0.9.2
>
> Searching for pyopenssl>=0.13
>
> Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyopenssl/
>
> Best  match: pyOpenSSL 0.13.1
>
> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.1.win32-`py2.7.exe#md5=02b016ed32fffcff56568e5834edcae6`
>
> Processing pyOpenSSL-0.13.1.win32-py2.7.exe
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 9, in module
>       load_entry_point('setuptools==1.1.6', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1925,
>    in  main
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1912,
>    in  with_ei_usage
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1929, in  lambda
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in
>    setup     dist.run_commands()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 374, in run
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 590,
>   in easy_install
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 641, in install_item
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 687,
>    in process_distribution
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 568, in resolve
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 806, in best_match
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 818, in obtain
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 609, in easy_install
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 639, in install_item
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 792, in install_eggs
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 869, in install_exe
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1379, in  extract_wininst_cfg
>
> **UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 27: ordinal  not in range(128)**

Someone help me please!

Warm Regards,
Rithy

Answer (score 1):

If using Python 2.x, you can comment this offending line:

```
# config = config.decode('ascii')
```

in easy_install.py (near line 1510):

```
# Now the config is in bytes, but on Python 3, it must be
#  unicode for the RawConfigParser, so decode it. Is this the
#  right encoding?
config = config.decode('ascii')
cfg.readfp(StringIO(config))
```